# Make checkbox selecton visible on cart

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, methods, get

I am trying to make checkbox selection visible inside cart and get them with the $GET method inside my form to display them inside the email.

```js
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_price); ?>" id="checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_size); ?> <span>+ <?php if(isset($currency_menu) && !empty($currency_menu)){ echo esc_attr($currency_menu);}?><?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_price); ?></span>
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("input[id='checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>']").click(function(){

        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){ 
          var price3 = parseFloat($("#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price4 = parseFloat($("#checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>").val());
          var totalprices = ( price3 + price4 );

          $('span.price-<?php the_id();?> input#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>').val(totalprices);  

          var price_latest1 = parseFloat($("#price-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price_latest2 = parseFloat($("#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price1 = parseFloat($("#testprice_<?php the_id(); ?>").val());
          var price_n = price_latest1 + ( price_latest2 - price1 );
          var price_latest_all = Math.round( price_n * 1000)/1000;

          $('span.price-<?php the_id();?> input#pricelatest-<?php the_id();?>').val( price_latest_all );
        }

      });

      $("input[id='checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>']").click(function(){
        if( !$(this).is(':checked')  ){
          var price3_after = parseFloat($("#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price4_after = parseFloat($("#checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>").val());
          var totalprices_after = ( price3_after - price4_after );

          $('span.price-<?php the_id();?> input#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?><?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_size); ?>').val(totalprices_after);

          var price_latest1 = parseFloat($("#price-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price_latest2 = parseFloat($("#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price1 = parseFloat($("#testprice_<?php the_id(); ?>").val());
          var price_n = price_latest1 + ( price_latest2 - price1 );
          var price_latest_all = Math.round( price_n * 1000)/1000;

          $('span.price-<?php the_id();?> input#pricelatest-<?php the_id();?>').val( price_latest_all );


        }
      });

    });
  });

</script>
```

```html
**The Cart**
<table>
  <tbody  id="mycart">
  </tbody>
  <tbody  id="name_foodid">
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<div class="row" id="options_2">

</div><!-- Edn options 2 -->
<label>
  <p class="fsize"><u>Hinweis:</u><br>
    Eine Lieferung ist erst ab einem Mindestbestellwert von 10€ innerhalb<br> Kaiserslauterns und 25€ ausserhalb von Kaiserslautern möglich.</p><br>

  <input type="radio" id="check" checked ="checked"  onclick = "Check1()" value=""  name="option_3">
  <?php echo esc_html__('Lieferung', 'quickfood' );?>

</label>
<!--<label>
<input type="radio" id="check1"  onclick = "Check2()" value=""  name="option_3">
<?php echo esc_html__('Take Away', 'quickfood' );?>
</label>-->
<hr>
<table class="table table_summary">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cart-total"><?php echo esc_html__('Zwischensumme', 'quickfood');?> <em class="pull-right"><?php if(isset($currency_menu) && !empty($currency_menu)){ echo esc_attr($currency_menu);}else{}?><span>0</span></em>
          <input type="hidden" name="total-hidden-charges" id="total-hidden-charges" value="0" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--<td>
Delivery fee <span class="pull-right"><?php if(isset($currency_menu) && !empty($currency_menu)){ echo esc_attr($currency_menu);}else{}?><?php echo esc_attr($delivery_charge );?></span>
</td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="total">
        <div class="cart-total2">GESAMT <em class="pull-right"><?php if(isset($currency_menu) && !empty($currency_menu)){ echo esc_attr($currency_menu);}else{}?>&nbsp;<span>0</span></em>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<form action="<?php if(isset($select_pages_checkout)){ echo get_page_link($select_pages_checkout); }else{echo "#";}?>" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_menu"  id="id_menu" value="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="delivery_charge"  id="deliverry" value="<?php echo esc_attr($delivery_charge );?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="total-hidden-charges2"  class="total-hidden-charges2" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="check"  id="check-hidden" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="phone-store"  id="phonenumber" value="<?php echo esc_attr($phone_number);?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="working-period"  id="workingperiod" value="<?php echo esc_attr($working_period);?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="arrprice"  id="arrprice" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="arrname"  id="arrname" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="number_quantity"  id="number_quantity" value="" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn_full"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Weiter zum bestellen', 'quickfood' );?></button>
</form>

</div><!-- End cart_box -->
</div><!-- End theiaStickySidebar -->
</div><!-- End col-md-3 -->

</div><!-- End row -->
```

```js
**The form**

$name_buyer   = $_GET['name_buyer'];
$buyer_emails = $_GET['buyer_email'];
$price        = $_GET['price'];
$detailfood   = $_GET['detailfood'];
$currency     = $_GET['currency'];
$item_number  = $_GET['item_number'];
$food_group_ingredients_size  = $_GET['_cmb2_food_group_ingredients_size'];
$note        = $_GET['note'];
$body_email  = "<html><body><h2>".__('Neue Bestellung:', 'quickfood')."</h2>";
$body_email .= "<h4>".__('Folgendes wurde bestellt:', 'quickfood')."</h4>";
$body_email .= "<strong>Bestellnummer</strong>: ".$item_number."<br/>".            
"<strong>Käufer Email</strong>: ".$buyer_emails." <br/><strong>Buyer Information</strong>: <br/><strong>Address: ".$address_orders."</strong><br/>
<strong>Telefonnummer: ".$tel_order."</strong><br/><strong>Postal Code: ".$pcode_oders."</strong><br/><strong>Name: </strong>".$name_buyer."<br/>
  <strong>Delivery Day: ".$delivery_schedule_day."</strong><br/><strong> Delivery Time: ".$delivery_schedule_time."</strong><br/>
    <strong>Bestellung: </strong>".$detailfood."<br/>
      <strong>Weitere Zutaten: </strong>".$food_group_ingredients_size."<br/>
        <strong>Anmerkung: ".$note."</strong></html></body>";

$other_email = $theme_option['email_receive'];
$multiple_to_recipients = array($buyer_emails,$other_email);      

$subject = __('Order detail', 'quickfood');
$body    = $body_email;
$headers = __('From website', 'quickfood') . "\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

wp_mail($multiple_to_recipients, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Again I want to display the ingredients inside the cart and then send the information to the form, save it and send it to my mail.

Thanks in advance with the help for this.

Comment: It would be better for you if you took the time to just publish the few lines of code you have a question about. It's not fair to ask everyone to understand everything about your program before they can offer you help.

Comment: Sorry for that you´re right. I´ll shorten the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is most interesting to me:
This Line displays the name of the ingredient:

```js
<?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_size); ?>
```

So I tried adding this line to this line:

```js
if( $(this).is(':checked') ){ 
       var price3 = parseFloat($("#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>").val());
       var price4 = parseFloat($("#checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?><?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_size);?>").val());
       var totalprices = ( price3 + price4 );
```

But it displays NaN inside of the cart instead of the name + prize of the ingedient.

Here is the code:

```
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_price); ?>" id="checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>">*<?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_size); ?>* <span>+ <?php if(isset($currency_menu) && !empty($currency_menu)){ echo esc_attr($currency_menu);}?><?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_price); ?></span>
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("input[id='checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?>']").click(function(){

        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){ 
          var price3 = parseFloat($("#pricecase2-<?php the_id();?>").val());
          var price4 = parseFloat($("#checks_<?php echo $counts; ?><?php the_id(); ?><?php echo esc_attr($food_group_ingredients_size); ?>").val());
          var totalprices = ( price3 + price4 );
```